# Find copies of folders? (Not files)

Tags: file-management, deduplication

I have a dozen of folders that are duplicates. Within them are a few dozen folders that are duplicates so i have a few thousand copies of the same files and folders. Many of them are exactly the same while others have changes in a few files.

What utility can i use to delete folders that are copies of others with no changes? if one or more files in that folder have been changed i dont want it deleted (and i'd like the subfolders to have a shortcuts to a copy but thats not required). Is there a utility to do this?

Comment: Perhaps OS/2? Maybe Plan 9? There are lots of operating systems to pick from.

Answer (score 0):

I duplicator tool will identify duplicated FILES.  I would then use the folder's they are in as input to a DIFF.  [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is good for finding any difference in two folders.  [n-way Folder Diff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/n-wayfolderdiff/) will compare multiple roots but has much less friendly output.

Comment: I use duplicate cleaner but like i said i have thousands of these folders. I'd need something more automatic

Answer (score 0):

Don't know that there's going to be one tool to accomplish what you want.  But by combining, you may be pretty close.  Directory tools, comparison tools, duplicate file tools ...

Take a look at [Altap Salamander](http://www.altap.cz/salam_en/index.html) (shareware) & in particular it's Compare Directories utility.  Compare can use various methods or combinations; size, date/time, attributes, contents, & subdirectories.

So if you have two *similar* trees that you are looking at, it can quickly filter out those sections of the tree that are identical (based on your comparison method) & then start comparing the different trees that are left.

Two top level dirs. R: & S:.  R: is kind of the Source, & S: is kind of the Backup.  Originally they were the same, purposely duplicated, but over time there were additions to R: & otherwise rearranged & cleaned up.

The highlighted (red) directores are not identical (per my comparison method), so deleting any of the S: directories that are not highlighted will only remove duplicate directory trees.

A#1, _from_USR, beat, bla, black ... all can safely be deleted.

Now, _from_C is different (highlighted in red).

[image]

So if I jump into the _from_C directory & run another Compare, again the difs are highlighted & those not can be deleted.  So again I can safely delete from S: _ecclectic, _Instrumental, 12 Girls Band ...  Now some directories are entirely new in R: & not in S: at all, like _flv & 10cc.  And again some directories are different.  So if I jumped into the corresponding _metal directories & Compared from there, I would come up with more diffs.  In some cases I may have added an m3u or a screenshot (jpg) that didn't exist before, causing the diffs.  So essentially the same, but a thing here or there that makes them not actually compare.  And once you got into the bottom level directory in a particular tree, what the differences are becomes clear (usually).  (With MP3, MS, WMP has a habit of messing with MP3 tags, which will both change the file date/time & contents, but not necessarily the size.  I never use WMP because of that.)

[image]

Anyhow throwing a tool like Salamander into the mix (of various tools) I feel can be worthwhile.  (Not to mention that Salamander is an excellent file manager too.)

Comment: +1 but just noting i need the tool to find the directories for me. This one allows me to browse to both and ask it to check

Answer (score 0):

WinMerge is not totally automated, but you can delete whole sets of duplicate folders at once by control-clicking on them.

You can limit your search to only folders by changing the Filter: field from "*.*" to "*".

You can control-select all the duplicate folders and then delete the ones from the right or left side, or both.

In my case, it was a inherited PC where the previous user downloaded hundreds of zipped folders, extracted them in place (in the Users/***/Downloads folder) then either copied or re-extracted them into folders one level up.

It's was a rather tedious combinatorics exercise: I have to compare each of 20 or so folders against the other 19, but I can control-select the whole set and delete the unwanted ones.